# Error uploading project to Testflight. CFBundleIdentifier Collision Error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, testflight

I'm trying to upload an app to TestFlight with the Xcode 14.2, and I get this error on validation. The app has an action extension and a dynamic framework that's shared between
the extension and the app itself.

[image]

I'm really not sure what this is supposed to mean. Has anyone gotten this issue or have any ideas?

Comment: So it kind of looks like you are trying to embed the framework BOTH into your extension AND the app. I don't think this will work. You can try chaning 'Embed and Sign' to 'Do not embed' on the extension

Answer (score 0):

Please try looking for those IDs in your project build setting & also under the framework that was mentioned in Error, and try removing those IDs that you found on both and then make a build, and see if this helps.